# Java -Boolean expression of variable and it's inverse

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-operator, unary-operator

This is quite confusing.

Question: Give the value of each of these expressions.

```
x && !x
```

Would this be true or false?

Comment: You can't short circuit an 'and' unless the first operand is false, in which case, it returns false...

Comment: If you are a student, it might be good to try and figure out what confused you about this, and ask your professor about it. This is a pretty elementary question; you should have a firm understanding of this behavior. Chances are that whatever confused you will come up in other forms in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
true && !true => false
false && !false => false
```

the only other option is

```
Boolean x = null;
x && !x => NullPointerException.
```

Comment: Can I assign null to any variable in Java? Btw thank you for your response, very clear and demonstrative.

Comment: @JungleJeem You can assign it to any reference, just not a primitive.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood your question, but I don't see how that expression would ever evaluate to true. If x was to be set to True the !x would evaluate to False, and vice versa. The logical AND operation will only evaluate to True if both parameters are True. Since this will never be the case, the expression will always be False.

The short-circuiting only occurs if the left side is False. Then there is no need to evaluate the right side. The expression will never short-circuit if the left side is True.

Answer (score 0):

Always `false` except `x` is `null`

`&&` Called Logical AND operator. If both the operands are `true`, then the condition becomes `true`.

Comment: I said conditional beacause of this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html However your answer is very clear and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test it out yourself?

I don't see how short-circuiting is applicable . To check if its true, both sides of the AND operator must be true and there are no shortcuts in the event that the entire exp is true.

Answer (score 0):

In the theory may be some issue with multithreading, but only in the theory